# Logical Test in R - Alternative to While Loop

Tags: r, loops, statistics

So I'm new to **R** and I'm trying to achieve a task without using a loop.

I have a function which contains a while loop, here's an example:

```
  some.Function(x,y,z,i){
     //do stuff
     while(i>0){
        //do more stuff
     }
     return(x)
  }
```

What I'm wondering (and I can't find any evidence of online) is, can a while loop be substituted with a logical expression? (like, only do when i > 0)?

I know it seems crazy and everyone would just use an if/else, for etc, but I need to repeat a task over and over but without using loops or if statements and it's proving very difficult.

Comment: In general, `for` loops can be avoided by using vectorized operations (fast) or hidden under the rug of a `*apply` call (not much faster, just prettier). A requirement though is that each iteration be independent of the previous ones. A `while` loop on the other hand often involves such dependencies, hence it is unlikely it can be rewritten in a more efficient way. Of course everything will depend on what your real case is and if you want to show us a little more of what your code is doing, we might be able to help.

Comment: use  `i>0` to filter whatever it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

`inds <- i >0

some.func(x[inds], y[inds], z[inds])`

Although possibly better to put `x, y, z` into a data.frame